# Sauce labs integration with circle ci

Tags: selenium, saucelabs, nightwatch.js, circleci

I added these lines to the cirlce.yml file:

```
post:
    - wget https://saucelabs.com/downloads/sc-latest-linux.tar.gz
    - tar -xzf sc-latest-linux.tar.gz

test:
  override:
     - ./bin/sc -u $SAUCE_USERNAME -k $SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY -f ~/sc_ready:
       background: true
       pwd: sc-*-linux
     - while [ ! -e ~/sc_ready ]; do sleep 1; done
```

When circle ci runs i get this when the following line is run:

```
cd "sc-*-linux": ./bin/sc -u $SAUCE_USERNAME -k $SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY -f ~/sc_ready:
```

/home/ubuntu/.rvm/scripts/extras/bash_zsh_support/chpwd/function.sh: line 5: cd: /home/ubuntu/shopstyle-frontend/sc-*-linux: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

this is Kim from CircleCI.

Can you try this, instead?

```
"cd sc-*-linux && ./bin/sc -u $SAUCE_USERNAME -k $SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY -f ~/sc_ready:"
```

Comment: Hey Kim, still getting an error:

cd "sc-*-linux"
cd sc-*-linux && ./bin/sc -u $SAUCE_USERNAME -k $SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY -f ~/sc_ready
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/scripts/extras/bash_zsh_support/chpwd/function.sh: line 5: cd: /home/ubuntu/shopstyle-frontend/sc-*-linux: No such file or directory
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'